# Why is my sidebar CSS close animation activating on screen load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm using html, JS and Scss to set up a basic sidebar animation that after the user clicks a hamburger icon the sidebar slides in from the left and then closes if the user clicks on the sidebar.

I have an annoying problem where my sidebar's "close" animation is executing on page load. So on page load the sidebar starts fully opened and then slides out of view. It happens every time I refresh the page, although I noticed if I comment out my google font import (I'm mporting into my scss file) this problem doesn't happen quite as often.

I thought this might be due to how the browser is downloading my css file, so have tried preloading the css file with rel="preload" but it's had no effect.

I have a fiddle with the code, even though running the code in fiddle doesn't actually replicate the problem! Running that code in Chrome, Firefox or Edge does have the issue though. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/5c8d1vze/1/

```css
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap");

 .hamburger_container:focus {
   outline: none;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 }

 .hamburger {
   padding: 0.9375rem 0.9375rem;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
   transition-property: opacity, filter;
   transition-duration: 0.15s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   font: inherit;
   color: inherit;
   text-transform: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: visible;
 }

 .hamburger:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .hamburger.is-active:hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
 }

 .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner,
 .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::before,
 .hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
   background-color: #00b8c2;
 }

 .hamburger:focus {
   outline: none;
 }

 .hamburger-box {
   width: 2.5rem;
   height: 1.5rem;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
 }

 .hamburger-inner {
   display: block;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -0.125rem;
 }

 .hamburger-inner,
 .hamburger-inner::before,
 .hamburger-inner::after {
   width: 2.5rem;
   height: 0.25rem;
   background-color: #00b8c2;
   border-radius: 0.25rem;
   position: absolute;
   transition-property: transform;
   transition-duration: 0.15s;
   transition-timing-function: ease;
 }

 .hamburger-inner::before,
 .hamburger-inner::after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
 }

 .hamburger-inner::before {
   top: -0.625rem;
 }

 .hamburger-inner::after {
   bottom: -0.625rem;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic {
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic .hamburger-inner {
   transition: background-color 0.125s 0.175s ease-in;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic .hamburger-inner::before {
   left: 0;
   transition: transform 0.125s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335), top 0.05s 0.125s linear, left 0.125s 0.175s ease-in;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic .hamburger-inner::after {
   top: 0.625rem;
   right: 0;
   transition: transform 0.125s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335), top 0.05s 0.125s linear, right 0.125s 0.175s ease-in;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic.is-active .hamburger-inner {
   transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   background-color: transparent !important;
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
   left: -5rem;
   top: -5rem;
   transform: translate3d(5rem, 5rem, 0) rotate(45deg);
   transition: left 0.125s ease-out, top 0.05s 0.125s linear, transform 0.125s 0.175s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
 }

 .hamburger--emphatic.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
   right: -5rem;
   top: -5rem;
   transform: translate3d(-5rem, 5rem, 0) rotate(-45deg);
   transition: right 0.125s ease-out, top 0.05s 0.125s linear, transform 0.125s 0.175s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
 }

 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 /*** HEADER *** */
 /* Header Bar */
 .header {
   align-items: center;
   background: #1b262c;
   color: #00b7c2;
   display: flex;
   height: 3.125rem;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 0.3125rem 1.25rem;
 }

 /* Top Navbar */
 .desktop__navigation {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
 }

 .desktop__navigation div {
   display: none;
   padding-left: 1.25rem;
 }

 /* SIDE NAVBAR */
 .mobile {
   align-items: center;
   background: #1b262c;
   color: #00b7c2;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   justify-content: center;
   opacity: 0.7;
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   top: 0;
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
   width: 80vw;
 }

 .mobile .mobile__items {
   font-size: 2rem;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

 .open {
   display: flex;
   transform: translateX(0);
 }

 /* *** BODY *** */
 body {
   background-color: #0f4c75;
   font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
 }

 @media (min-width: 40rem) {
   .desktop__navigation div {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

```html
            <header class="header">
              <nav class="hamburger_container">
                <button class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic" type="button" id="hamburger-button">
                  <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </nav>
              <nav class="desktop">
                <div class="desktop__navigation">
                  <!-- Turn this into a drop down menu -->
                  <div>Courses</div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </header>
            <nav class="mobile" id="mobile">
              <ul class="mobile__items">
                <li class="mobile__item">CSS</li>
                <li class="mobile__item">JavaScript</li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

            <main>
            </main>
```

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I couldn't replicate your issue with your own jsfiddle file.

Comment: Looks like your font import is delaying the transition of `.mobile`. Did you try putting the `@import` statement at the end of your CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue locally. It seems that your font import statement is delaying the initial transform of the `.mobile` div.

The quickest "fix" to this would be to import the font at the end of your CSS file instead of the beginning. This resolved the issue for me the vast majority of times I refreshed, still happened a very few times.

Alternatively, I would recommend slightly rewriting your CSS so that the side menu starts hidden by default (without need for an initial transform), e.g. replace `transform: translateX(-100%);` by `left: -100%`.

Comment: Thanks Anis, really appreciate the help! Importing the font at the end of my CSS file didn't affect it too much but replacing transform with left has solved the issue. The font still loads in a bit slowly (and weirdly the middle bar of the hamburger icon loads in a bit slowly too), am I doing anything obviously wrong or missing a best practice here? Thanks!

Comment: @SignetOHara Not too sure about "best" practices, but usually when I use Google fonts, I include them using the provided stylesheet tag, e.g. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
` for the Roboto font, and never had any major issue doing that

Comment: And glad this answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered something similar myself in a couple browsers. The thing is objects with initial transition values sometimes display the default value (e.g. 0) and then when the page and css is loaded apply the transition afterwards, showing you the animation.

One fix would be to exclude the transition value from the initial class, then when the page is loaded, add the class "page-loaded" or so to the body and have something like

```
body.page-loaded #mobile{
    transition:0.5s;
}
```

in the css.

Comment: Thanks Rhellik, that's also a good suggestion. Seems its much better to not have animations executing on page load at all. Also, it's apparently better practice to link to the google font in the html file rather than importing it into CSS because it defers loading the font straight away which could also be screwing with the page's performance